# Batch build fails with vsts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, iar

I am trying to build IAR Embedded workbench code using VSTS batch script. The .bat file is located in TVFC repository hosted by Microsoft.

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.0\common\bin\IarBuild.exe"  "C:\embedded_programming\lesson2\project.ewp" -build Debug -log all
```

The builds terminates with an error "The system cannot find the path specified" as shown in linked image:

It don't know what I am doing wrong since I am new to VSTS but it works fine with Command Line Interface.

Please help!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Does your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the hosted agent, that's the problem. Your software isn't installed on the hosted agent, and there's no way for you to install it since the hosted agent is provided by Microsoft.

You'll need to set up a [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) that runs on a machine that has the appropriate software installed.